# Origen de la expresión "toque de queda"

Tags: etimología, modismos

El **toque de queda** es la prohibición circunstancial de circular por las calles de una ciudad. Por ejemplo, el gobierno portorriqueño declaró toque de queda durante las cuatro noches posteriores al huracán María, para evitar saqueos.

¿Por qué tiene este nombre tal situación? ¿Hay alguna historia según la cual se haya "tocado" algo para "quedarse"? ¿Y por qué se usa la preposición "de" en este caso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El Diccionario de Autoridades [1737] recoge

> QUEDA: El tiempo de la noche, señalado en algunos Pueblos (especialmente Plazas cerradas) para que todos se recojan, a que se avisa con la campana, y en la Milicia con el tambor. Llamase así por el efecto que causa, que es estarse todos quedos.

Creo que es autoexplicativo: se hace tocar una campana (o un tambor) para que todos se recojan por la noche y estén quedos (quietos).

Comment: Excelente, encontraste el origen.

Answer (score 4):

Creo que viene de "tocar" o hacer sonar una sirena o alarma para indicar a civiles o militares que deben de "quedarse" en (o acudir a) ciertas dependencias (sus casa o donde sea).

Solo he podido encontrar esta referencia en la web

> El nombre se deriva esencialmente de la práctica europea de, durante la guerra, después de cierto tiempo (por lo general la tarde), se hacía sonar una sirena de la población a abandonar las calles en caso de bombardeo.
>
> Fuente original: [Escuelapedia.com](http://www.escuelapedia.com/toque-de-queda/)

Este otro enlace relaciona el término en inglés (curfew) con el toque de una campana

> una campana era tocada a la puesta del Sol para dar noticia de que llegaba la hora de extinguir todas las fogatas y velas. A esto se le llamo "curfew", del francés "couvre feu", que significa "cubrir el fuego".
>
> Fuente original: [datosfreak](http://www.datosfreak.org/datos/slug/etimologia-curfew)

Es decir, que antiguamente este "toque" (de campana u otra alarma) era literal. Ahora puede ser simplemente una hora u otra condición establecida.

Comment: Claramente. Creo que es esto nomás.

Comment: Sobre **curfew** http://www.etymonline.com/word/curfew indica: "The medieval practice of ringing a bell at fixed time in the evening as an order to bank the hearths and prepare for sleep. **The original purpose was to prevent conflagrations from untended fires.** The modern extended sense of "periodic restriction of movement" had evolved by 1800s."